# Parallel Population of Nested List

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

The code below appears to work - that is, fill an outer List with sub-Lists of incremental integers.

Am I just lucky?

I'm beng careful to pre-allocate "slots" and not cross over.

```
class Program
{
    static List<List<int>> allLists;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        allLists = new List<List<int>>(553);

        for (int i = 0; i < 553; i++)
        {
            allLists.Insert(i, new List<int>());
        }

        Enumerable.Range(0, 552).AsParallel().ForAll((i) => InsertRange(i));
    }

    static void InsertRange(int index)
    {
        allLists[index] = Enumerable.Range(0, 7205).ToList();
    }
}
```

Is there ever a danger that one list will trash another?

Comment: Why are you creating all those empty lists only to overwrite them? Why are you using `Insert()` instead of `Add()`? Most importantly, why are you even using `List` instead of an array, if you want a collection with a fixed amount of elements?

Comment: Insert is way better because even if one thread somehow interrupts another it is likely to not cause loss of data.

Comment: @MrFox 1. That part of the code is completely synchronous, there is no other thread at that point. 2. Parallel `Insert()`s wouldn't work because: a. `Insert()` is certainly not thread-safe. b. You can `Insert()` just after the last position in the list, but not beyond that.

Comment: If I do not pre-populate the outer list first then I definitely get problems with sub-Lists interferring with each other. As @MrFox suggested, when the list has to grow, then there's problems. I want them to be Lists because I use other Linq queries against them once filled.

Comment: But you don't need to populate the outer list with actual lists, using `null`s would be much better. And you can use LINQ queries with arrays too, because arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing different parts of an array in parallel is thread-safe in .Net. And since `List<T>` is backed by an array, I *think* your code should also be thread-safe.

But I think you're overcomplicating things. You can use PLINQ to generate all the inner lists and then use `ToArray()` to create the final array (or `ToList()`, if you really want to create `List<T>`). Since PLINQ has its own versions of [`Range()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.range) and [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413744) (and [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413364)), I believe this will be also more efficient.

So, I would rewrite your code like this:

```
allLists = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 552)
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 7205).ToList())
    .ToArray();
```

Of course, this all makes sense only when parallelizing creating the inner lists will actually speed up your code, but you will have to measure that by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

yes you should lock inside the InsertRange method. But make sure the creation of elements is still done in parallel:

```
private static Object settingValue = new Object();
static void InsertRange(int index)
{
    // This part can be executed in parallel.
    List<int> values = Enumerable.Range(0, 7205).ToList();

    lock (settingValue)
    {
        allLists[index] = values;
    }
}
```

Edit: it could be that you are just lucky, since creating the list will cost considerably more time that assigning the reference to the index number the chances are small one assignment will exactly overlap the other.

Comment: As `index` is a local variable I figured it would never potentially take more than one value per thread and therefore be safe.

Comment: I must say you got me doubting, but the problem can also lie in the List code itself, it's not atomic. Maybe the only time when you are at risk is when the list needs to grow, but you initiate the list at the size needed. The only way I see to test it is increase the chance of collisions happening, reduce the range to 0, 1 then if all data is still correct you are probably right...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Potential pitfalls with PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997403.aspx) you can have a potential non-thread safe method InsertRange(int index)